# Temporary redirection from two directories deep to the root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this directory structure:

```
|-language-A\
|-language-A\program-A
|-language-A\program-B
|-language-A\program-C
|
|-program-A\
```

Currently `program-A` is not translated to the `language-A` but somehow Google was able to crawl this directory and now it's showing in the search results. I need to redirect `language-A\program-A` to `program-A` in the root ... not all the folders inside `language-A` just that directory. This is a temporary redirection as I will remove that rule once that translation is ready.

So basically it will be something like:

`http://example.com/language-A/program-A/what-ever`

To:

`http://example.com/program-A/what-ever`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question really doesn't say much so I will assume all strings are fixed and there are no parameters to pass:

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/language-A/program-A/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*    program-A  [R,L]
```

Redirects temporarily

`http://example.com/language-A/program-A`

To:

`http://example.com/program-A`

All according to your question: `I need to redirect language-A\program-A to program-A in the root...`

#### UPDATED

According to question update:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/language-A/program-A(.*)?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*    program-A%1  [R,L]
```

Redirects temporarily

`http://example.com/language-A/program-A/what-ever`

To:

`http://example.com/program-A/what-ever`

`/what-ever` is optional and will be passed if exists.

Comment: Will give it a try. I meant also to redirect all the content in the `program-A` directory too like `http://example.com/language-A/program-A/whatever` to `http://example.com/program-A/whatever`

Comment: Please update your question with all you need. I will update my answer accordingly.